# Find $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} e^{n+\frac{1}{n}}-e^n$?

Tags: limits

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} e^{n+\frac{1}{n}}-e^n$

I tried multiplying and dividing with $e^{n+\frac{1}{n}}+e^n$ and then doing l'hopital, but I got nowhere

Comment: $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{e^{1/n} - 1}{1/n} = 1$$

Answer (score 0):

$e^{n+1/n}-e^n=e^n(e^{1/n}-1)={e^n\over n}{{e^{1/n}-1}\over {1\over n}}$. You have
$lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}{{e^{1/n}-1}\over {1\over n}}$ is the derivative of $exp$ at $0$ so $is$ $1$ and $lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}{e^n\over n}=+\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:$$e^{n+\frac{1}{n}}-e^n=\frac{e^n}{n}\frac{\left(e^{\frac{1}{n}}-1\right)}{\frac{1}{n}}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} e^{n+\frac 1n}-e^n=\lim_{n \to \infty}e^n(e^{\frac 1n}-1)=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{e^n}{n}\left(\frac{e^{\frac 1n}-1}{\frac 1n}\right)=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{e^n}{n}\underbrace{\left(\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{e^{\frac 1n}-1}{\frac 1n}\right)}_{=1}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{e^n}{n}\\=\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{e^n}{n} \rightarrow \infty$$

Answer (score 0):

You don't need L'Hospital rule. Note that $e^x-1=(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\ldots)-1>x$ for every positive $x$ and $e^{n+1/n}-e^n=e^n(e^{1/n}-1)$.